# Unable to deploy Google App Engine with Java 11 Runtime

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, ktor

I was using Java 8 runtime on my Ktor project until now and the project was getting deployed without issues but now as I migrate to Java 11 runtime, I am having issues.

I was using appengine-web.xml and web.xml to specify the description but since I am migrating I've created a app.yaml file that looks like this :

```
app.yaml ->
runtime: java11
entrypoint: 'ProjectName-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar'
instance_class: F1
automatic_scaling:
  max_pending_latency: 500ms
  min_idle_instances: 1
  max_idle_instances: 1
  max_concurrent_requests: 80
  min_instances: 1
  max_instances: 1
  target_cpu_utilization: 0.95
  target_throughput_utilization: 0.95
```

I've updated the JAVA_HOME variable to point to the Java 11 installation directory.
I 've updated my build.gradle (groovy) to include the following :

```
build.gradle ->
sourceCompatibility = 11    
targetCompatibility = 11
```

Here is the error log on google cloud console after running the "gcloud app deploy" command:

```
Starting Step #2 - "build"
Step #2 - "build": Already have image (with digest): asia.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/buildpacks/google-gae-18/java/builder:java_20231016_RC00
Step #2 - "build": ===> ANALYZING
Step #2 - "build": ERROR: failed to initialize analyzer: getting previous image: getting config file for image "asia.gcr.io/projectName/app-engine-tmp/app/default/ttl-18h:latest": GET https://storage.googleapis.com/asia.artifacts.prjectname.appspot.com/containers/images/sha256:{theHashCodeHere}?access_token=REDACTED: unexpected status code 404 Not Found: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>NoSuchKey</Code><Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message><Details>No such object: asia.artifacts.projectname.appspot.com/containers/images/sha256:{theHashCodeHere}</Details></Error>
Finished Step #2 - "build"
ERROR
ERROR: build step 2 "asia.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/buildpacks/google-gae-18/java/builder:java_20231016_RC00" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior may be encountered due to transient issues within `App Engine’s` infrastructure causing a race condition within the deployment process, attempting to get an image that may not be present yet within the `GCS bucket` in which these images are stored by default.

Another possibility could be that part of the image, or perhaps the bucket in which these images are stored may have been deleted.

I believe that this issue may be caused by a transient issue within `GAE’s architecture`.

The possible solutions might be:

1. Retry this operation after a few hours which may result in successful deployment.
2. Using the `gcloud app deploy` command with the [`--no-cache`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy#--cache) flag  helps solve the issue at once. This is because the `--no-cache` flag allows the `build step` within the deployment process to not use cached images, and might resolve the conflict occurring within the build operation for the affected `App Engine` instance.

Comment: Thanks I used --no-cache and it worked...